# ASP.NET two login

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to have two login transaction on ASP.NET Project? One login is for administration which handle administrative transaction and the other one is for member? Also, what is the proper structure to organize web forms for all administrator pages and members pages.

Comment: Why not to use role based logins? Why you want to have logins?

Comment: I'm building a shopping cart project which users and customer are separate.

Comment: So Give user role to users and customer role to customers. So you can differentiate users based on roles